# Creating a Single Entity with @SecondaryTable makes full join instead of Inner join JPA hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using the following code to collect data from two different tables, but it's giving me records from the meal table even if there are not any records in the allergies table but I want to do a INNER  JOIN from both tables instead. I don't want to get any records from the  meal table if I don't have any records in the allergies table that match the same id inside the meals table.
Please advise I have been stock with this for days.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meal")
@SecondaryTable(name = "allergens", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "meal_id"))
class Meal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "peanuts", table = "allergens")
    boolean peanuts;

    @Column(name = "celery", table = "allergens")
    boolean celery;

    @Column(name = "sesame_seeds", table = "allergens")
    boolean sesameSeeds;

    // standard getters and setters

}
```

Comment: what query are you using to get Meals?

Answer (score 0):

If the identity is driven by the `allergens` table then you should map the entity to that table and use the `meals` table instead as secondary table.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(JOINED)
public abstract class Allergens {

}

@Entity
public class Meals extends Allergens {

}
```

Comment: Hi Christian, I tried that and it working but it's giving me empty meal data when there is some records in allergies but I want to get data only when the primary key id exists in both tables like an inner join, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Chris, made more research and the issue is that it's giving the secondary table as "optional = true" but I need "optional = false" for the secondary table, please help.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is joined inheritance instead. Create an abstract entity class mapping to one table and a subclass mapping to the other.

Comment: Hi Christian could you please share an example of how to create the joined inheritance instance instead, thanks in advance. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that is working using: "@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "allergens", optional = false)":

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meal")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "allergens", optional = false)
@SecondaryTable(name = "allergens", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name ="meal_id"))
class Meal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "peanuts", table = "allergens")
    boolean peanuts;

    @Column(name = "celery", table = "allergens")
    boolean celery;

    @Column(name = "sesame_seeds", table = "allergens")
    boolean sesameSeeds;

    // standard getters and setters

}
```